# Счетчик с использованием только стилей

Tags: html, css, html5

Можно ли с помощью только CSS заставить счетчик работать? Ведь стрелочками в `input` можно увеличивать и уменьшать значение, используя только `type="number"`.

```
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
    <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
</div>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/530zfLt0/).

Comment: Нельзя. Нужен JavaScript код

Comment: То, что можно увеличивать и уменьшать значение этого поля без дополнительных телодвижений -- особенность реализующих это браузеров и в общем случае [необязательно](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить вашу задачу с использованием только CSS нельзя. Нужен JavaScript код. Если использовать jQuery, то код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
(function() {
    var quantity = $('#num_count');

    $('#button_plus').click(function() {
        var value = parseInt(quantity.val(), 10);

        if (value < quantity.attr('max')) {
            quantity.val(value + 1);
        }
    });

    $('#button_minus').click(function() {
        var value = parseInt(quantity.val(), 10);

        if (value > quantity.attr('min')) {
            quantity.val(value - 1);
        }
    });
})();
```

**UPD:**

А вот и JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8atb9d9L/